# If Shri khishna was ahir/abhir. Why did abhirs attack Arjuna when he was escorting wife's of soilders?

Tags: yadavas

Krishna says that l will be born among you abhira. Yadav's(ahirs) trace their lineage to king yadu. They also trace their lineage to Krishna.  Then why was Arjuna attacked by abhirs when he was escorting the wife's after sinking of dwarka?